# Question about function pointers, map and templates

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates

I'm learning about function pointers and maps. I have to use function pointers and maps to write a replication of switch-statements without using if or switch.

I want to write a function execute() that take two arguments "a" and "b" and do an operation with the appropriate operation character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;


// define the function pointer fptr, templated
template <typename T>
using fptr = T(*)(T, T);

template <typename T>
T plus(T a, T b){
    return a + b;
}

template <typename T>
T minus(T a, T b){
    return a - b;
}

template <typename T>
T multiply(T a, T b){
    return a * b;
}

template <typename T>
T divide(T a, T b){
   return a / b
}

// Call back the function pointer on two variables
template <typename T>
T operation(fptr<T> f, T a, T b){
    f(a, b);
}

// Execute map to fit an operation character to an operation function pointer

template <typename T>
T execute(T a, T b, char c){
    std::map<char, fptr<T> > m;
    m['+'] = &plus;
    m['-'] = &minus;
    m['*'] = &multiply;
    m['/'] = &divide;

    return operation(m[c], a, b);
}

int main(){
    execute<int>(1, 2, '+');
    execute<double>(1.2, 3.4, '/');
}
```

These below are the errors that I got. I got no typos in the call back, but the errors still say ambiguous. I wonder why that happen. I really appreciate the suggestions. Thanks a lot!

```
error: reference to 'plus' is ambiguous
    m['+'] = &plus;
              ^
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'plus'
T plus(T a, T b){
  ^
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::__1::plus'
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS plus : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, _Tp>
                        ^
error: reference to 'minus' is ambiguous
    m['-'] = &minus;
          ^
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'minus'
T minus(T a, T b){
  ^
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::__1::minus'
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS minus : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, _Tp>
                        ^
```

Comment: Try `&plus<T>`.

Comment: @jarod42: it doesn't work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You're missing a semicolon in `divide()`, as well as the `return` in `operation()` - not as important as the rest.

2) There's a reason `using namespace std;` is frowned upon. There are template functor types called `std::plus` and `std::minus` which are having name collisions. The reason this is not the case for the others is because they don't have name collisions with stuff in the `std` namespace (i.e. they are `std::multiplies` and `std::divides`).

I suggest you remove the `using namespace std;` and just be explicit when you want `std` stuff, but a fix without doing that is to use `&::plus<T>` which means: get the address of `plus<T>`, which is located in the global namespace (i.e. not in the `std` namespace).

Also you don't need to specify the type for `execute()`, as they can be deduced from the arguments you give it (just make sure the arguments are the same type).

Answer (score 2):

The is a `std::plus` [class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) and you have elevated it to the global namespace so it's conflicting with your function name. Remove this line:

```
using namespace std;
```